# Author access to DispalyName field

Tags: sitecore

Our site page naming works like this: The name of each page/folder item in our site tree is entered in a URL friendly way, like: my-page-name. Then, we update the Display Name field to be something more friendly: My Page Name, which makes the Content Editor easier to read and we use Display Name in code to show in navigation, etc.

This has worked great for development, but we're setting up author roles so we can hand the keys over to authors to add content.

Most things are working as we expect, except it's not clear how to give our author role access to the Display Name field so they can name pages per the above set up.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to give them `write` access to `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Appearance/Appearance/__Display name`

Comment: No go. Just for kicks I gave them full permissions to that field to do what ever they want and the Appearance section and display name field still won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. Display Name also shows up in the Ribbon and it appears that it works or my author role. So, I don't need make the Display Name field show up under the Appearance section.

Comment: Do you have `Standard Values` checked? It's an option under the View tab of the ribbon, it's this that shows the Appearance section of values.

Comment: yeah, that was part of how I figure that out, I checked it and then could see all the other sections. However, I don't want content authors being able to do this, so I cut off permissions to the standard values checkbox for my author role. Now they can use the Display Name button in the ribbon and not see all the other fields. Works for me.

Comment: Cool. You can also restrict fields (i.e. everything but display) but what you have done is the right way.